# Parse every variables (from a C file) on Visual Studio Code Extensions API

Tags: javascript, c, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm currently making a VSCode extension and I would like to parse every variables from the current file.
The problem is that vscode.commands.executeCommand('vscode.executeDocumentSymbolProvider', activeEditor.document.uri) seems to return only global variables or at least it doesn't return most variables which are declared in functions.
On the DocumentSymbol doc, there is the "children" attribute which should do exactly what I want but it seems like it's working only for classes and not for normal functions.

I would like to find another way than just reading throught all the brut code, a DocumentSymbol array contening all the variables is needed for what I want to do later with these.

For example:

```
#include "stdio.h"


void test(float test);

int a;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{  
   int b;
   float c = 44;
   for(b = 0; b < c; b++)
   {
       printf("%f",c);
       int d;
       d = c;
       printf("%d", d);
   } 
   /*
   int shouldNotBeFound;
   */
   test(c);

   return 0;
}

void test(float test)
{
   int e;
   e = test + 4;    
   printf("%d", e);
   e ++;
}
```

Here, my goal is to get an array of DocumentSymbol from a to e and maybe with argc, argv and test too.
For the moment, using executeDocumentSymbolProvider, I'm getting, only the variable a and the functions main and test but main.children doesn't return anything.

Thanks